# Mysql escape square brackets

Tags: mysql, escaping, special-characters

I need to execute the following sql query in my mysql db:

```
SELECT * FROM phpbb_posts WHERE post_text LIKE '%][quote%';
```

Looks like mysql doesn't understand this statement because i see null results while such text persist in many rows of the table.

Maybe some sort of escaping should be used in such case?

Comment: Nope, that should work fine. `[` and `]` are not required to be escaped.

Comment: Are you sure that your regex is correctly finding things in `post-text` ?

Comment: You can even try like `WHERE post_text LIKE '%quote%'`

Comment: it works fine when i use '%quote%' or even '%[/quote]%'. but doesn't work for '%][q%'

Comment: I have the same problem, when I use specific characters in a search query, including [].

Comment: I was using `str_word_count()` before creating the query. That filters them out, if you don't include the square brackets in the last argument :-)

Comment: I am also stuck with this issue . Not able to query the string [0.0,23,9]